# how to use circular scrolling using synaptics touchpad

Tags: synaptics

I have used that feature in windows and I have always wanted to try that feature on this ubuntu raring.Using gsynaptics doesn't work it shows grey or deactivated buttons on circular scrolling.
Is there anyway of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1):

- Use this link it may work for you.
  http://digiwanderlust.blogspot.in/2008/06/do-you-love-way-you-scroll-on-your-ipod.html
- In my case "/etc/X11/xorg.conf" file wasn't there.
- It's location is "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf"
- Follow the same instruction given in the link.

Or simply

1. `gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf`
2. In the section where you find

> Section "InputClass" 
>               Identifier "touchpad catchall"
>               Driver "synaptics"

In the end of that section add

```
   
Option "CircularScrolling" "on"
Option "CircScrollTrigger" "3"
Option "VertTwoFingerScroll" "on"  //two finger scrolling ....
Option "HorizTwoFingerScroll" "on"  // similar 
Option "PalmDetect" "on"
```

Save the file properly and restart .

Remember you need superuser privilages to make changes to file.

Hope it helps :)